# Alternatives to C and asm on microcontrollers

Tags: c++, c, embedded, msp430

My background is like this: embedded/C, then C++, then higher level OO languages (Java, Scala, Ruby, Groovy, etc.), and now I am doing a small project involving MSP430 microcontroller. Meanwhile, inspired by that, I am contemplating a number of potential pet embedded system projects (meshes and/or RTLS look appealing). So my question is focused primarily on MSP430 for now, though, as an aside, I'd love to have a broader picture, too, involving other microcontrollers.

I was a bit surprised finding out that, after so many years, I might need to go back to C, with its macros, naming conventions, and all. My brain used to be wired for C, but that was many, many years ago.

So what alternatives are available?

1. C++ feels much more agreeable to me, and, fortunately, seems doable: http://stonepile.fi/object-oriented-approach-to-embedded-programming-with-c/

   So if I am to program C++, I just need to inline a lot, avoid virtual functions when possible, and I should be good, right? (at least, memory-wise; they did not benchmark for performance at the above link).

   However, if it's so easy, why do people program C? I must be missing something.
2. The above link also seems to provide a wrapper library for pico]OS. Has anyone used picoOS on MSP430, how reliable is it, and how much resources does it take?
3. What are the pros and cons of Energia for a simple MS430 project? I tried it, it seems very intuitive and self-documenting, but does it result in as neat a code under the hood? For instance, does Energia initialize unused GPIO to the off state to save energy? Does it initialize unused interrupts? What is the overhead in terms of memory and speed? Etc.

   Edit: As a long-time Eclipse person, I'd love to use CCS. I saw that Energia sketches can be imported to CCS. Does  it mean that CCS have full support for Energia and can be used as an Energia IDE?
4. Has anyone used Java Grinder http://hackaday.com/2014/02/10/java-grinder-spits-out-dspic-and-msp430-assembly-code/ ? It seems appealing, but because it spits out an Assembly and not C/C++ code, it's a bit scary to commit to it: what if I am locked into it and it's not ready for the prime time? If it generated C code, I could have easily dropped it if it did not work.
5. I mentioned Java and my question was deleted, as it's self-evident that other than grinder-like syntactic sugar (not that I mind syntactic sugar!), Java can't run on MSP430. I guess I'll ask another question re WHERE Java can run. This has already grown too long.
6. What other languages/environments are out there, that fill the niche between low- and hig-level languages?

Comment: This question is _way_ too broad for stack overflow.

Comment: In short: It is possible to use C++ for small controllers and works quite well. Just avoid anything from the standard library, that might involve dynamic memory allocation.

Comment: Should I split it into multiple questions? I thought about that, but that felt a bit like spam/flood.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, what if I accidentally use something from standard library, what will be the consequences? Is there a tool that goes through the code and catches this?

Comment: If you can find a Java Virtual Machine (JVM) for your platform, Java can be used.  You may be able to compile Java to native instructions for your platform.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews, my platform is way too tiny for a JVM, not to mention, TI has produced such a multitude of microcontrollers that no one in their right mind will invest in adapting to all of them. Compiled Java sounds more feasible, only what's the smallest known garbage collector?

Comment: If you can find a cross compiler for your platform, you can also use FORTRAN and other compiled languages.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews, oh no, not FORTRAN. Something that was invented after C++.

Comment: You may have to disable the garbage collector.  Read up on the specs of the JVM.  Many embedded systems don't use Java because of the garbage collector; as dynamic memory is evil in embedded systems, primarily due to fragmentation.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews, how do you use Java without garbage collector and dynamic memory?

Comment: @ТаняТ. There's no need for an extra tool, the linker will tell you. Usually you don't provide an implementation for the `new()`/`delete` operators on such small systems.

Comment: So, the people who've put me on hold - I am a newbie here. Would you please explain the format in which you'd like to see this question? Split into multiple separate questions? I've tried that, and then got yelled at for not putting enough thought into my questions and not doing my homework; because taken separately, that's precisely what it looks like. At least, when they are together, it's clear that I've done my homework! I am not clear what's expected of me, it's still a hit or miss for me.

Comment: On C++ in embedded: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5710942/c-on-small-footprint-microcontrollers/5721471#5721471 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2855884/use-the-right-tool-for-the-job-embedded-programming/2860753#2860753.  But no - do not "inline a lot" - it will make your code huge.  A non-virtual member function call in C++ has no more overhead than a C function call.  You have to learn to stop making your questions so broad if you want them to stay alive - post multiple separate questions - you will get better more focussed answers and more of your points covered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you seem to have several questions here so I shall go through in the order you numbered them.

1. Most micros will indeed run C++ (assuming the manufacturer or an open source project provides a compiler back-end), however you have to be wary of a number of drawbacks. C++ Is less deterministic, as in, it provides a significantly higher level of abstraction, which one likely does not want an a resource constrained embedded system, and by and large it is not needed either as embedded systems are rarely powerful enough to usefully run the enormously complex algorithms that warrant a high level language like C++. It is also likely to cause a wide range of hard to track bugs, given the difficulty of debugging code from an embedded system having bugs which are simple and easy to trace are very much nicer. However very importantly, the C++ standard libraries are enormous, they will use excessive ram and very likely waste much of your limited memory space. Thus, even if you do use C++, you wont be able to use any of the techniques that make it powerful.
2. Simply, I have not used it, however like any RTOS, it is useful if you want a slightly higher level interface, however for a micro the tiny size of the MSP430 it seems overkill, I cannot imagine you doing anything on there that warrants an ROTS, if you need multitasking it would be better to provide simple cooperative tasking yourself.
3. Unfortunately I have not used that platform either, however given it is based on wiring, my guess it that it does not provide high levels of hardware specific optimization, if you want that I recommend using it for the bulk of your code but make calls into lower level libraries when needed. Beyond that however, it does provide a lovely, self documenting interface, I strongly encourage you to try it. It will also make your code many times easier port if you switch to another micro later (many systems from many companies provide wiring bindings).
4. You really answer this yourself here, it could be very powerful but is still very immature, I would avoid it purely because of this lock-in until it becomes more mature, then it is worth re-assessing.
5. Java works nicely on more powerful ARM chips, that is the only place I have seen it in wide use, and implemented fairly efficiently in a micro (ARM provides hardware assistance specifically for Java). Other than this Java is a poor fit for the micro world, at one point it appeared it might go somewhere but this was largely unrealized, for now C likes are the way to go for smaller micros.
6. Unfortunately there is not really a huge amount of choice other than C. My best recommendation is using higher level libs like wiring. That gives you slightly nicer interfaces without killing efficiency, otherwise there is little point in using a tiny micro if you need high levels of abstraction.

In summary, C does a fairly good job here, I do not think there has been any motivation or effort to make a good replacement. And frankly I largely feel this way too, C never became a bad language, it is still well suited for small systems for the same reasons as it was before. It provides power, efficiency and predictability.

I hope this helps somewhat, if you have any queries please comment me and I will see what I can do to help.

Comment: wow, thank you so much for a great answer. Lots of questions: 1) what other high level libs like wiring (Energia in my case) are there? 2) Why did Java processor effort die? 3) I completely forgot that C/C++ links statically! You are right, I don't want any standard libraries! However, what if I just use C++ without any libraries at all, like in the link I provided in my question, would that work? (OTOH, why bother, wiring seems a straightforward choice) 4) How easy is integration between wiring and C, especially involving CCS? 5) tbc

Comment: 5) what I hear you say is this: use Wiring for high level, abstract stuff, then integrate it with C for low-level stuff, and thus get the best of both worlds; in the same way it was once recommended to use Java for high-level stuff and then use C and Java/Native Interface for the low level stuff and tight loops. Did I understand you right? If I did, that sounds like a strategy I can follow!

Comment: Also, would you please read the "Edit" paragraph in my question?

Comment: @ТаняТ. 1) uClibC is good (provides something close to standard libs for micros). You may also find some good SDKs for micros even provide POSIX subsets, though you need to check your manufacturer as they are always chip specific (I think TI does this on some chips). Beyond this they mostly tend to be platform specific so google would be your friend here. 2) the java language started as a tiny subset of today's java and could fit nicely on small micros, as it became more complex, simple traditional implementations became insufficient, could not support new features so people gave up on them.

Comment: @ТаняТ. 3) Indeed, you can do this, gcc and a few other compilers allow this. However it is possible, however I personally found that C++ without any libs at all provides little more than C, you will also find that most embedded compilers do not provide advanced language features like generics so you do not gain much and lose some efficiency. If you like object oriented principles micro developers do often practise object oriented C. You do not really need an OO language to structure your code well. You will also find some libraries do not link safely with C++ due to subtle ABI differences.

Comment: @ТаняТ. 4) It should be very easy, on every implementation I know of they share an ABI and calling convention you you just link them in the obvious way, wiring should even happily read C function prototypes and work fine. However if you find an implementation where they do not work I would be very interested to see it. 5) This is exactly what I do mean indeed, you get it perfectly I think, Java and C is a good analogy. I have had much success with that process and do not see any reason it should not work on any platform that supports it. I am glad to have helped :)

Comment: @ТаняТ. With regards to your edit; My understanding is that CCS will indeed work with Energia, it is C like enough that it imports and is compatible with most IDEs I have seen, there may be tiny issues but they are easy to work around. I can also recommend that approach and have had it work before. If you have any issues I can try to help. ps, a couple of those extension questions (particularly 2) may make interesting questions on their own, try asking them and see if you get any better answers.

Comment: Apart from the caution on the use of the C++ library, most of the C++ comment is unfounded opinion.

Comment: @Clifford I agree that there is a significant element of opinion in that comment, would it help if I added some references, how could I change the point to make it more objective? Please suggest some ideas, or if you like edit it to be more factual. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: I have to agree with @Clifford.  If you are used to OO languages on desktop systems, going back to C is just nightmarish.  OK, so you may have to avoid the std lib, but any C++ is preferable to C.  I use C++ on embedded systems with 8K of RAM, (OK ARM, not MSP430).

Comment: @MartinJames: You may have misrepresented my position (albeit unintentionally) - I used C++ on embedded targets *before* using it on a PC - PC development is something I seldom do.

Comment: @Clifford - heh, I only use C++ for embedded.  On PC, I use mostly Delphi, (essentially OO pascal).  Every time I have to use C for some legacy maintenance, I just hate it:)

Comment: @MartinJames I must ask, what specifically do you dislike about C? I have used it for everything from writing a bootloader to writing a large scale network application and have never found it lacking? What specifically do you miss that makes it so unsuitable for your tasks?

Comment: Classes, encapsulation, inheritance, polymorphism.  Yes, I do use that stuff:)   Examples - all my I/O for CAN, UART, SD have the same interface.  All my system objects can be passed to an I/O channel and all have a virtual method to serialize themselves as text - very useful for debugging.

Comment: @Vitaly:  C++ *supports* OOP.  While you can implement an OOD in C, there is no language specific support for the paradigm, so OOD to C leads to a less clear and concise expression of the design than C++.  But even without OOD/OOP C++ is all of C and more - a bigger tool bag, why would you not want that? Even using just the subset of C++ that is C but using a C++ compiler you are likely to end up with better code through stronger type checking, and it will be no larger or less deterministic.  The *"C++ is less deterministic"* comment is particularly misleading.

Comment: @Clifford I particularly see your point regarding the mention of less deterministic. What I am really trying to convey is that if one uses more advanced language features and abstractions it can become difficult to debug issues as the core problem can become hidden behind layers of abstraction, however I may change the wording to make that clear, it is not the language as a whole that causes it, just certain features.